# Pointer not updating

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* removeNegatives(int *v, int *totv){

int i, j, aux=(*totv), t=0;

for(i=0; i<aux; i++){

    if(v[i]<0){

        t=v[i];

        for(j=i; j<=aux; j++){

            v[j]=v[j+1];
        }

        v[(*totv)-1]=t;
        aux--;
        i=-1;
    }

    else{

        continue;
    }
}

totv=&aux;

v=(int*)realloc(v,(*totv)*sizeof(int));

return(v);

}

int main(){

int *totv=NULL, *v=NULL, *z=NULL, i, j=0, a;

printf("How many numbers are you entering?\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("Enter them, then:\n");

totv=&i;

do{
    if(j<(*totv)){

        scanf("%d",&a);
        v=(int*)realloc(v,++j*sizeof(int));
        v[j-1]=a;
    }

}while(j<(*totv));

printf("\n");
printf("Size before: %d\n",*totv);

z=retiraNegativos(v,totv);

printf("Size after: %d\n",*totv);
printf("\n");

printf("[ ");

for(i=0; i<(*totv); i++){

    printf("%d ",z[i]);
}

printf("]");    

printf("\n");

free(z);
return(0);
}
```

I'm resizing the vector *"v"* according to the number of negative numbers the user has entered.

But the problem is that the pointer *"totv"* is not updating after I call the fucntion *"removeNegatives"*.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A classic one (dozens of duplicates) : parameters __including pointers__ are passed by value in C.

Comment: Even if it were "updating", how would you expect it to work? Inside `removeNegatives` you are making your `totv` to point to a *local variable* `aux`. That local variable is destroyed when function finishes.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly so it would be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
totv=&aux;
```

You assign your local copy of some pointer to a new address. This does not have any visible effect outside your function. What you actually wanted is not changing the pointer, but the value it points to, thus you need:

```
*totv=aux;
```

Additionally, you have a problem here:

```
for(j=i; j<=aux; j++)
    v[j]=v[j+1];
```

In the last iteration, you will access your array at positions `aux` and `aux + 1`, both out of range of your array, at least on the first removal! Instead, you need:

```
for(j = i; j < aux - 1; j++)
```

or a little more elegant in my eyes:

```
for(j = i + 1; j < aux; j++)
    v[j - 1]= v[j];
```

Some further hints:

- You do not need any `else continue;`, if there isn't anything to follow the else branch anyway.
- No need to restart the loop (`i = -1;`) right from the start, you can simply go on with the value you just copied (`--i;`). However, although technically not incorrect, prefer not modifying the loop variable of a for loop. This is something one does not expect from this kind of loop. If you really have to, then prefer a while loop instead.
- You do not need to copy the removed values to the end if you cut them off afterwards anyway.
- And if you do not want to keep the removed values, do not copy all the subsequent values each time you remove one value, prefer copying every value to be kept just once, see below.

Moving all elements in one go:

```
int* p = v;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < aux; ++i)
{
    int tmp = v[i];
    if(tmp >= 0)
        *p++ = tmp; // copy current value to first free position
}
```

An array with values `{ 1, -2, -3, 4, 5, -6, 7 }` would now look like this:
`{ 1, 4, 5, 7, 5, -6, 7 }`. The last values just remain unchanged, p points to the first position to be cut off. So:

```
aux = p - v;
*totv = aux;
return (int*) realloc(v, aux * sizeof(int));
```

Be aware that you could return NULL this way, if reallocation fails. I'd assume this to be very unlikely, if reducing size, but for correctness:

```
p = realloc(v, aux * sizeof(int));
return p ? p : v;
```

So you'd return the unchanged array on failure. Consider some more fine-tuned error handling...

Answer (score 3):

This may look unrelated to your question, but it isn't.

Consider this:

```
int foo(int bar)
{
  bar = 123;
}
...
int x = 1;
foo(x);
// What's the value of x here?
...
```

Will `x` be updated after the call to `foo`?

Comment: *But but. . I am passing pointer and I read somewhere it causes the caller to see the changes*. I really find it difficult to answer such questions. To some extent SO is responsible for this. Some answers just provide a solution without any explanation and get accepted limiting further discussion. *Sigh*